# Is there any term for attributing the function typical of one thing to another thing with a different function?

Tags: expressions, terminology

Sometimes, especially in fantasies, we attribute the function typical of one thing to another thing with a different function. For example, we say "X's ears saw something", "X's heart cried for something", etc. I wonder if there is any specific term to describe these types of phrases. The only term that comes to mind is "personification", but it's something different.

Thanks to @AndyBonner, the famous quote from William Shakespeare's A Midsummer Night's Dream provides a good example for the term I'm looking for, if there is any:
"The eye of man hath not heard, the ear of man hath not seen, man's hand is not able to taste, his tongue to conceive, nor his heart to report what my dream was" (4.1).

Comment: You mean beside "metaphor"? Maybe _function_ isn't the right word for what you're looking for. I mean, ears are not designed to hurt, but you can say _his ears hurt_ without attributing any function.

Comment: I suspect it is a form of transferred epithet. See https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zmfc7ty/articles/zhrsf4j

Comment: @JohnLawler - But, for example, it's eyes that see, not ears!

Comment: @Greybeard, But transferred epithets are only about adjectives, aren't they?

Comment: Could you edit the question to clarify: Are you interested in intentional uses that "mix metaphors" for poetic or descriptive effect ("his impatient fingers tap-danced on the table"), or for confusion and mistakes, like in *A Midsummer Night's Dream* ("The eye of man hath not heard, the ear of man hath not seen, man's hand is not able to taste, his tongue to conceive, nor his heart to report, what my dream was.")

Comment: Going back to the Greeks, we have the four humors and various *sympathies* "A (real or supposed) affinity between certain things, by virtue of which they are similarly or correspondingly affected by the same influence, affect or influence one another" (OED)

Comment: Five primary types of "semantic transference" are ***simile, metaphor, metonymy, personification*** and ***synechdoche***. There's also the very specific term ***anthropomorphise*** when we "transfer" ***human*** "attributes" to other things (not necessarily even *living* things).

Comment: Verbal surrealism.

Answer (score 1):

Those would be examples of **synecdoche.** [MW defines this as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche)

> a figure of speech by which a part is put for the whole (such as *fifty sail* for *fifty ships*), the whole for a part (such as *society* for *high society*), the species for the genus (such as *cutthroat* for *assassin*), the genus for the species (such as *a creature* for *a man*), or the name of the material for the thing made (such as *boards* for *stage*)